# Ubuntu 16.04 pyqt5 multimedia example missing plugins

Tags: pyqt5, qtmultimedia

I am trying to check out a `pyqt5` multimedia [example](https://github.com/baoboa/pyqt5/blob/master/examples/multimediawidgets/player.py), but I get this error every time I start it (in a pop-up window):

```
The QMediaPlayer object does not have a valid service.
Please check the media service plugins are installed.
```

I found suggestions on the internet, like install `libqt5multimedia5-plugins`, but no luck. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had configured Qt from source and got the same problem as you and finally solved it.

Problem is Qt cannot find the path of mediaservice

Solution 1 ) is add QT_PLUGIN_PATH to your environment variable and give your plugins path. Detailed image is  [image: here]

Solution 2)
is copy the /plugins/mediaservice directory into your executable.

Example: debug directory must contain   myexample.exe and mediaservice directory. 
Like in this [image]

Answer (score 0):

Qtmultimedia depends on gstreamer. For Ubuntu 16.04 you want the version 1.0 stuff and most plugins including ugly and bad. I aslo have qgstools, libqt5gstreamer, sessioninstaller, and just to be safe I also installed totem which uses gstreamer and I hoped it would pull in the necessary gstreamer stuff. Pyqt multimedia works for me showing videos , playing mp3s, saving pictures and oggs from my /dev/video0 camera, except for some reason the oggs have an extraneous .jpg tacked on the end.

Comment: Could you specifiy the packages and how you installed `pyqt5`? I was not able to install it based on your suggestions :(